# Java - copying a variable's value instead of referencing it

Tags: java

I know this is a basic Java question yet I have never seen a full solution to this problem. Basically, I want to copy another variable's value into another variable and then have the newly created variable preserve that value.

Here is my code :

```
private void someMethod() {

    String tmpCommand = commandName;
    commandName = modelItem.getName();

}
```

Here, `tmpCommand`'s value will change to `modelItem.getName()` value since it references `commandName`
. However, what if I want `tmpCommand` to not change value whenever `commandName` value is changed? Would I have to create a new object `tmpCommand`?

Comment: "I want to copy another variable's value into another variable and then have the newly created variable preserve that value."  This is what Java does and Java doesn't support any other approach.  It can't do what you say you don't want (Unlike C++ which can do it if you really want to, but not by default)

Comment: "since it references commandName". Typical misconception, which is probably coming from languages like C/C++. It doesn't reference commnadLine, it references an object that commandLine refers to. Assignment here means copying a reference from var commandLine to var tmpCommand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Here, if `tmpCommand`'s value will change to `modelItem.getName()` value since it references `commandName`.

No, it won't. The value of `tmpCommand` is *just* the value of `commandName` at the time of the assignment.

That's really simple to demonstrate:

```
String original = "foo";
String test = original;
original = "bar";
System.out.println(test); // Prints foo
```

Note that changing the value of `original` is *not* the same as changing the data within the object that the value of `original` refers to. Let's do a different example with a mutable type - `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder original = new StringBuilder("foo");
String test = original;
original.append("bar");
System.out.println(test); // Prints foobar
```

Here, both `test` and `original` still have the same value: that value is a *reference* to a `StringBuilder` object. The call to `append` doesn't change that reference at all... it changes the data in the object that the reference refers to. It's *really* important to differentiate between variables, references and objects.

So if you want to avoid that, you'll need to create a new object with the same content - some classes provide a way of doing that; others don't. For example, you could use:

```
StringBuilder original = new StringBuilder("foo");
String test = new StringBuilder(original);
original.append("bar");
System.out.println(test); // Prints foo
```

When a `clone()` method is provided, that could be used too. But basically the idea is that sometimes you want two variables to hold references to *independent* objects.

Comment: Oh really? Hmm, the book I am reading must contain errors then haha. I need to demonstrate this myself.

Comment: Or, you misunderstood the book. That's an option too you know, more likely too.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I didn't read carefully enough and that was why I was confused later on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work as it is, since once `commandName` is assigned `modelItem.getName()`, it no longer refers to the same object as `tmpCommand`. That said, Strings are immutable, so you couldn't change the contents of these objects anyway.